# Algebra tricks in the problem of player gambler's ruin.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, stochastic-processes, proof-explanation

Let $$S_k=1+(q/p)+\cdots+(q/p)^k =
\begin{cases}
k+1,  & \text{if $p=q$;} \\
\frac{1-(q/p)^{k+1}}{1-(q/p)}, & \text{if $p\neq q$.}
\end{cases}$$

If we substitute $S_k$ in $$v_k=\frac{S_{k-1}}{S_{N-1}}(1/p) \sum_{i=0}^{N-2} S_i -(1/p)\sum_{i=0}^{k-2} S_i$$, then we get

$$v_k=\begin{cases}
 \\
\frac{1}{q-p} \left(k-N\frac{1-(q/p)^{k}}{1-(q/p)^N}\right), & \text{if $p\neq q$.}
\end{cases}$$

I don't see how to get $v_k$.
Can somebody explain this please?

Note: I think we are just using the $p\neq q$ case in $S_k$ to get $v_k$.
And also, $k=1,2,...,N-1$.

Comment: I forgot to add my attempts, when I made the substitution, I got this: $\frac{1}{p} \frac{1-(q/p)^{k}}{1-(q/p)^N} \sum_{i=0}^{N-2} S_i -\frac{1}{p} \sum_{i=0}^{k-2} S_i $

Comment: and the question is Where $k$ and $N$ came from (in the result) ????

Comment: There are $k$s and $N$s in the definition of $v_k$?

Comment: In the original answer, $v_k$ had the case where $p=q$ but I only care for the $p\neq q$ case.

Comment: @Shuri2060 no, there are not k's and n's in the definition, but there are in the last equation of $v_k$ i.e. in the final result

Comment: $$v_k=\frac{S_{k-1}}{S_{N-1}}\frac{1}{p} \sum_{i=0}^{N-2} S_i -\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=0}^{k-2} S_i$$
There are ks and Ns right there?

Comment: @Shuri2060 well yes, $N-2? $or $k-2?$. Not in the explicit form, like K alone or N alone

Comment: When you substitute $S_x$ in, they'll be there. In addition, there'll be likely be identities involving them to simplify expressions to get you there.

Comment: @Shuri2060 You already did it right? can you post it (like an answer) please? Because I'm confuse.

Comment: No - I'm only starting and I'm stuck since I'm not very good at manipulating monsters like this lol.

Comment: Making the substitution I get this: $1+...+\frac{1-(\frac{q}{p})^{N-1}}{1-\frac{q}{p}}$ this is from the first summation

Comment: What is $v_k$ definition for dummies ?

Comment: @Marine1 it means the mean time given that the markov chain starts at state $k$.

Comment: @Marine1 you could google 'Player gambler's ruin' for more interesting things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p \neq q$.

We have

$$S_k=\frac{1-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{k+1}}{1-\frac{q}{p}}$$

and

$$v_k=\frac{S_{k-1}}{S_{N-1}}\frac{1}{p} \sum_{i=0}^{N-2} S_i -\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=0}^{k-2} S_i$$

Substituting, we get:

$$v_k=\frac{1}{p}\left(\left({\frac{1-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{(k-1)+1}}{1-\frac{q}{p}}}\right)\left({\frac{1-\frac{q}{p}}{1-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{(N-1)+1}}}\right)\sum_{i=0}^{N-2} S_i -\sum_{i=0}^{k-2} S_i\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{p}\left(\left({\frac{1-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{k}}{1-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{N}}}\right)\sum_{i=0}^{N-2} S_i -\sum_{i=0}^{k-2} S_i\right)$$

---

Now

$$\sum_{i=0}^{K} S_i={\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)}^{K}+2{\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)}^{K-1}+...+n{\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)}^{K+1-n}+...(K+1){\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)}^{0}$$

$$={\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)}^{K}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{K}(i+1){\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)}^{i}\right)$$

Let $x=\frac{p}{q}$.

Then

$$\sum_{i=0}^{K} S_i={x}^{-K}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{K}(i+1){x}^{i}\right)$$

$$={x}^{-K}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{K}\frac{d}{dx}{x}^{i+1}\right)$$

$$={x}^{-K}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i=0}^{K}{x}^{i+1}\right)$$

$$={x}^{-K}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{1-{x}^{K+1}}{1-x}\right)\right)$$

$$=x^{-K}\left(\frac{1-{x}^{K+1}}{1-x}+x\frac{-(K+1){x}^{K}(1-x)+1-{x}^{K+1}}{(1-x)^2}\right)$$

$$=x^{-K}\left(\frac{-(K+1)(1-x){x}^{K+1}+1-{x}^{K+1}}{(1-x)^2}\right)$$

$$=\frac{x^{-K}-(K+2){x}+(K+1){x}^{2}}{(1-x)^2}$$

---

Substituting in (and still letting $x=\frac{p}{q}$):

$$v_k=\frac{1}{p}\left(\left(\frac{1-x^{-k}}{1-x^{-N}}\right)\left(\frac{x^{-N+2}-Nx+(N-1){x}^{2}}{(1-x)^2}\right)-\left(\frac{x^{-k+2}-kx+(k-1){x}^{2}}{(1-x)^2}\right)\right)$$

$$=\frac{\left({1-x^{-k}}\right)\left({x^{-N+2}-Nx+(N-1){x}^{2}}\right)-(1-x^{-N})\left({x^{-k+2}-kx+(k-1){x}^{2}}\right)}{p(1-x)^2(1-x^{-N})}$$

$$=\frac{(k-N+Nx^{-k}-kx^{-N})x(1-x)}{p(1-x)^2(1-x^{-N})}$$

$$=\frac{x(k(1-x^{-N})-N(1-x^{-k}))}{p(1-x)(1-x^{-N})}$$

$$=\frac{x}{p(1-x)}\left(k-N\frac{1-x^{-k}}{1-x^{-N}}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{q-p}\left(k-N\frac{1-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{k}}{1-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{N}}\right)$$

Comment: OMG definitely this algebraic problem is a monster.

Comment: @AaronMartinez Not necessarily - it's more likely that I haven't spotted a shortcut or I've made an error somewhere. Currently I'm working with $\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{q-p}(\frac{1}{x}-1)$ as a hopeful shortcut I could've used earlier.

Comment: Oh I see thanks

Comment: @AaronMartinez Finally done. Looking back, it actually wasn't that bad tbh. Out of interest, would you mind passing a link on where this formula comes from?

Comment: Thank you! yes, hmm It will take me some time to find the web page again, but when I find it I will let you know.